# How to use -vf and -filter_complex in same command in FFMPEG

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, gif

I am converting video to gif in FFMPEG on mac using the following:

```
ffmpeg -i screenAnimation2.mov -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse -r "12" -s 300x200 -loop 2 screenAnimation2.gif
```

Which works great, but I'd like to only specify the width, and keep the aspect ratio, which can be done using the scale filter:

```
ffmpeg -i screenAnimation2.mov -i palette.png -lavfi paletteuse -r "12" -vf "scale=300:-1" -loop 2 screenAnimation2.gif
```

However, this outputs the error:

```
Filtergraph 'scale=300:-1' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

Is there a way round combining the 2 filters? Or perhaps a way to obtain correct height value and avoid using the scale filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them in a single complex filter:

```
-lavfi 'paletteuse,scale=300:-1'
```